How to implement generic classes in components?
Right now the app contains several near-identical components. Each of them is basically a list view of data models with a search bar to filter the list.
For each of these components:

Input is the initially selected item;
Output is a select(item) event emitter;
The component encapsulates an API call to retrieve the list of items.

So their functionality is practically identical. Load an array of models from the API, render them in a list view, offer a sarch bar for filtering of the list and expose the selected item from the list to the parent component.
Use case:
...
<app-customer-search [initialSelection]="myCurrentCustomer"
                     (select)="onSelectCustomer($event)>
</app-customer-search>
...

...
class CustomerComponent {
    ...
    initialSelection = input<Customer>();
    select = output<Customer>();
    ...
}

and:
...
<app-contract-search [initialSelection]="myCurrentContract"
                     (select)="onSelectContract($event)>
</app-contract-search>
...

...
class ContractComponent {
    ...
    initialSelection = input<Contract>();
    select = output<Contract>();
    ...
}

What I would like to achieve is to rewrite the two components into one, i.e.
<app-select-item [modelClass]="Customer"
                 [apiFunc]="loadCustomers"
                 [initialSelection]="myCurrentCustomer"
                 (select)="onSelectCustomer($event)>
</app-select-item>

and
<app-select-item [modelClass]="Contract"
                 [apiFunc]="loadContracts"
                 [initialSelection]="myCurrentContract"
                 (select)="onSelectContract($event)>
</app-select-item>

In other languages like C# one might use generic classes. Like
class ItemSelectComponent<T> where T: class, new()
{
    ...
}

Assuming we call the model class T, I would like to type the input as input<T>(), the API function as Func<Observable<Array<T>>> and teh output as EventEmitter<T>.
Is there any way to do this in Typescript?

We can use generics on the component to achieve this, we can pass in the API call method and subscribe to the result inside the inner component, below is a working example for reference also.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-common',
  template: `
    @for(item of items(); track $index) {
      <div>
      @for(column of columns(); track $index) {
        {{item[column]}} | 
      }
      </div>
    }
  `,
})
export class Common<T> {
  initialSelection = input<T>();
  select = output<T>();
  apiFunc = input<Observable<T[]> | null>(null);
  items = signal<T[]>([]);
  columns = signal<(keyof T)[]>([]);

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.apiFunc) {
      this.apiFunc()?.subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.columns.set(Object.keys(response[0]) as (keyof T)[]);
        this.items.set(response);
      });
    }
  }
}

Key takeaways:

We can use the T generic type defined on the top of the component to type all the types of the properties.
We can use the first row data to get the keys, a better solution is for you to provide the columns manually.
I use keyof T to ensure that the columns will be of the properties names of T.

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  inject,
  Injectable,
  input,
  output,
  signal,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Customer {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  customerId: number;
}

export interface Order {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  orderId: number;
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DummyService {
  getCustomers() {
    return of([
      { name: 'test', id: 1, customerId: 123 },
      { name: 'test2', id: 2, customerId: 1234 },
      { name: 'test3', id: 3, customerId: 1235 },
    ]);
  }
  getOrders() {
    return of([
      { name: 'test22', id: 1, customerId: 1233 },
      { name: 'test22', id: 2, customerId: 12344 },
      { name: 'test23', id: 3, customerId: 12355 },
    ]);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-common',
  template: `
    @for(item of items(); track $index) {
      <div>
      @for(column of columns(); track $index) {
        {{item[column]}} | 
      }
      </div>
    }
  `,
})
export class Common<T> {
  initialSelection = input<T>();
  select = output<T>();
  apiFunc = input<Observable<T[]> | null>(null);
  items = signal<T[]>([]);
  columns = signal<(keyof T)[]>([]);

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.apiFunc) {
      this.apiFunc()?.subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.columns.set(Object.keys(response[0]) as (keyof T)[]);
        this.items.set(response);
      });
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [Common],
  template: `
    <app-common [apiFunc]="customerApi$"/>
    <app-common [apiFunc]="ordersApi$"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  dummyService = inject(DummyService);
  customerApi$ = this.dummyService.getCustomers();
  ordersApi$ = this.dummyService.getOrders();
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

you don't have to pass the "class". typescript can infer the generic type from arguments of a function, or here from type of the input.
class ItemSelectComponent<T> {// can be "T extends Customer | Contract" to restrict the T
    initialSelection = input<T>();
    select = output<T>();
}

<app-select-item 
                 [initialSelection]="someNumber"
                 (select)="onSelectNumber($event)> // $event is of type number 
</app-select-item>


Yes, you can achieve this in TypeScript by using generic components and extracting the shared logic. While TypeScript doesn't directly support generic components, you can simulate them using interfaces, inputs, and dependency injection.
Here’s how you can create a reusable app-select-item component:

Define a Generic Interface to outline the structure of your models and the API function.
Create the Generic Component SelectItemComponent to handle common functionality.
Use the Generic Component SelectItemComponent for both Customer and Contract models.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
